# Why doesn't Firefox remember my previous searches on Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey, wolfram-alpha

I've entered a lot of queries into wolframalpha.com.  When I go back to the site, and try to type in something I've typed before, nothing happens.  On other sites, like superuser.com, if I type into the search box, Firefox remembers my previous queries and suggests them to me.  Why doesn't this work on Alpha?  Can I make it work with a greasemonkey script?

```
<form method="get" action="/input/" accept-charset="UTF-8" autocomplete="off">
    <div id="input-background">
        <input name="i" id="i" maxlength="200" autocapitalize="off" type="text">
        <a id="iClear" style="display: none;"></a>
        <label class="hidden" for="equal">Calculate</label>
        <input id="equal" title="compute" value="Submit" type="submit">
        <div id="howTo"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha's search box has `autocomplete="off"` property, and hence this is respected by browsers and the input box is not filled in. I couldn't find any greasemonkey scripts to change this behaviour

---

There is [an alternative](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:yxZPCM2NQ0wJ:www.peetm.com/blog/%3Fcat%3D28+autocomplete%3D%22off%22+wolfram+alpha&cd=7&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us), however. **Keep in mind - that this enables auto complete for everything**.

```
1. Locate Firefox’s installation folder. Normally that’s C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox

2. Navigate to the components folder.

3. Open nsLoginManager.js in an editor.  As Notepad won’t do really, do this instead [if you've a proper editor, just go to step 4]:

3a) Select  Start | Run

3b) Enter cmd <enter or Ok>

3c) type cd C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\components <enter>

3d) type edit nsLoginManager.js <enter>

3e) Go to step 4.

4. Find this:

    /*
     * _isAutoCompleteDisabled
     *
     * Returns true if the page requests autocomplete be disabled for the
     * specified form input.
     */
    _isAutocompleteDisabled :  function (element) {
        if (element && element.hasAttribute("autocomplete") &&
            element.getAttribute("autocomplete").toLowerCase() == "off")
            return true;

        return false;
    },
5. Change it to this:

    /*
     * _isAutoCompleteDisabled
     *
     * Returns true if the page requests autocomplete be disabled for the
     * specified form input.
     */
    _isAutocompleteDisabled :  function (element) {
        return false;
    },
6. Save the file [if you're following the 3x) steps above, select File | Exit, and when asked if you want to save the edited file, answer Yes.  To close the command prompt, enter exit <enter>].

Note that you might first have to change the file’s security permissions to do this [you DO if the save fails].  E.g., in Vista I had to A) right-click on the file [e.g., in Explorer] B) select Properties | Security. B) select Edit. C) select your username, D) change the persmissions to include Write access.

And you’re done – either start, or close/re-start Firefox!
```

Comment: Aha!  I've also seen the opposite, where a credit card field is marked as autocomplete=on, and it remembers when it shouldn't.  It would be great if there were an extension or script that let us individually disable/enable it for special cases like this.

Answer (score 2):

And here's how to enable it for a specific site using Greasemonkey:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Alpha autocomplete on
// @namespace      
// @description    Enables browser form history for Wolfram Alpha
// @include        *wolframalpha.com*
// ==/UserScript==

document.forms[0].setAttribute("autocomplete", "on")
```